# Add box with custom per-page properties

Tags: post-meta, metabox

Hey,
I'm stuck trying to add a box with settings for all pages (the ones users create/edit).
What I'm attempting to do is add 6, 7 check boxes and an input field for all pages that alters the rendering of it; for example: *"Display a contact form at the bottom yes/no?"*.

How do you do this without, of course, editing any Wordpress core files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress these boxes are called "meta box" and to add one to your new/edit page screen you can use [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function (look at the example at the bottom for the examples), you can also use [**this class**](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) which is nicely documented and does most of the job for you. Or you can use a plugin like [Verve Meta Boxes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/) which does all of the job for you and you just add the options you want form its UI.